# Verify the following arguments are valid using Valid Argument Forms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am given the following and need to break this down into a valid argument form chart

q -> r
~q -> (u ^ s)
s -> (w v r)
~r
*----------*
therefore
~w -> r

I so far have down in statement reason format (please enter answers in this format) 
~r            given 
q->r          given 
~q            Modus Tollens 
s -> (w v r)  given 
w             elimination? (this is where I get confused should this be s -> w?)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have derived ${\sim}q$ by modus tollens, so look to the third premise ${\sim}q\to(u\land s)$.

Having thereby derived $u\land s$ by modus ponens, you may derive $s$ by *whatisitcalled* rule.

Now you may invoke the premise $s\to(w\vee r)$.

Having now derive $w\lor r$ by modus ponens, look again to the premise ${\sim}r$ so you may derive $w$ by *whichisitnamed* rule.

Having done that, you now need to derive ${\sim}w\to r$.

So what methods do you know that allow you to deduce such a conditional statement?

---

$$\begin{array}{|lrr}~~1.~q \to r\\~~2.~{\sim}q \to (u \wedge s)\\~~3.~s \to (w \vee r)\\~~4.~{\sim}r\\\hline ~~5.~{\sim}q &\text{modus tollens }&4, 1\\~~6.~u\wedge s&\text{modus ponens }&2, 5\\~~7.~s&\text{what is it called }&6\\~~8.~w\vee r&\text{modus ponens }&3, 7\\~~9.~w &\text{what is it named }&8, 4\\~~~~\vdots\\13.~{\sim}w\to r&\text{some reason}&\mathsf{???}\end{array}$$

Comment: lol thank you much Graham.